# Macro to open file with Current date

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to open a file that the file name will change each day because of the current date.

File\today_20120723 for today.

I am trying this but it isn't working. Suggestions

```
Dim OpenPath As String
Dim OpenName As String

OpenPath = "N:\File\": OpenName = OpenPath & "today_" VBA.Format   (Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"



Workbooks.Open Filename:=OpenPath
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think what you mean is `VBA.Strings.Format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple lines of code in a single line is really a pain to read.

That said, I'm not sure what `VBA.Format` is doing in your code, but this should work:

```
OpenPath = "N:\File\"
OpenName = OpenPath & "today_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer by just a second! had to upvote you for it. :)

Comment: I think what he means is `VBA.Strings.Format`.